# Why use Python's `open()` function to open file descriptors?

Tags: python, io-redirection

Python's builtin `open()` function [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#oct) reads (emphasis mine)

> *file* is a path-like object giving the pathname (absolute or relative to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or **an integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped**. (If a file descriptor is given, it is closed when the returned I/O object is closed, unless closefd is set to `False`.)

It's not clear to me to which file descriptor's process it is referring to, nor if it is possible to refer to the file descriptor's of any process or how to do it.

Experimenting for a bit in an interactive shell, I figured out the process it is referring to is the shell itself.

My question is: how is it that this is useful in a way that passing strings isn't?

Comment: Say something else opened a file descriptor for your code to use (e.g., something opened a privileged file and then dropped privileges, and passed it to a python script). How else are you going to use it in Python?

Comment: @muru Can you please make your example concrete with code? I'm sure I'm missing something that I can't quite see. One concrete question that I have in response to your comment is: how is it that "something else" is going to open a file descriptor in my running instance of the Python shell?

Comment: so, You cannot always open everyting just by passing the string-path to this object, the good example of those object are all the IPC objects like, queue, pipes etc. Those object are managed by system, and the usually doesn't have explicit path